# A public action method 'undefined' was not found on controller '#######'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, undefined

Maday,
i'm getting this error logged in db any idea or clue to fix this intermittent asp.net mvc exception.
thanks

```
Unhandled System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): A public action method 'undefined' was not found on controller '#######'.
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.HandleUnknownAction(String actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)    at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.HandleUnknownAction(String actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for sure, but I suspect this is the result of a URL being constructed in JavaScript where a variable is not being defined.

Something like:

```
var action
var url = '/myContoller/' + action
```

This will result in a request to:

> /myContoller/undefined

The intended URL could be for something that isn't even intended to be an MVC route.  It could be for an image or something.

```
var imageUrl
var url = '/folder/' + imageUrl
```

> /myFolder/undefined

MVC will try to route that, depending on how your routing is configured.

Is there any information in your logs about where the requests are coming from?

**Update 1:**

If you want MVC to ignore all requests to a particular area of your site (images directory for example), you can do something like this:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("images/{*pathinfo}");
```

Comment: thanks for replying, is there any techniques or tool to catch this exceptional routing

Comment: A public action method 'undefined' was not found on controller 'Kernel.Web.Controllers.APController'.

Comment: There may be other methods, but my experience is you need some sort of logging that will capture the referrer.  That will give you an idea of what script the bad request is coming from.  Then fix the script.

Comment: i need to ignore my Images folder for not to be routing in Global.asax how i could do this.

Comment: I updated the answer with the information I think you are looking for to ignore an images folder.

Comment: thanks Dan,i could ignore it by using this code: routes.IgnoreRoute("{controller}/undefined");  but i'm trying the root causing the issue with no success

Answer (score 0):

I have discerned a possible way to fix the image URL routing problem, based on @Dan's [helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18489598/1298685):

---

So, because I have this "catch-all" route for 404 errors in my `RouteConfig.cs`:

```
// for 404-error page routing
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Error",
    url: "{*url}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Error", action = "PageNotFound" }
);
```

...MVC is oddly interpreting images that I have loaded via a Razor `@foreach` statement as URL's:

```
// this is triggering the weird problem, dunno why:
@foreach (string image in this.Model.ImageArray)
{
    <img src="@this.Url.Content(image)" title="foobar" alt="@image" />
}
```

The Exception type is `HttpException` and the Exception message generated is:

> **A public action method '[object HTMLImageElement]' was not found on controller 'MyWebsite.Controllers.HomeController'**

---

Placing `routes.IgnoreRoute("MyImageFolderPath/{*pathinfo}");` at the top of the `RegisterRoutes` method in my `RouteConfig.cs` did *not* resolve this issue, but this did:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("[object HTMLImageElement]");
```

It still seems hackish though, and due to my poor implementation of handling 404-errors...

You can verify that it works though by sprinkling breakpoints throughout your `RouteConfig.cs`, and also in the `Application_Error` method in `Global.asax.cs` (if you are also handling `HttpException` errors there).